How can I set the tick labels of my colorbar to a different color?
I am creating an image using the function below. Because I later want to integrate it into a window, I am changing the background color and as a result the text is not visible with the default color. I want to change the tick labels of my colorbar to be displayed in white (or any contrasting color).
Below you can see what I am currently doing:
 def create_image(self):

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), facecolor=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

        values = [hexagon['value'] for hexagon in self.sensorMatrix]
        cmap = plt.get_cmap(custom_colormap)
        norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.min([i for i in values if i != 0]), vmax=np.max(values))

        for i, hexagon in enumerate(self.sensorMatrix):

            hexagon_color = cmap(norm(hexagon['value']))
            hexagon_edge = hexagon['edge']

            hexagon_coords = self.coordinates[i]
            hexagon_polygon = plt.Polygon(hexagon_coords, edgecolor=hexagon_edge, facecolor=hexagon_color, linewidth=1)

            ax.add_patch(hexagon_polygon)

        ax.set_xlim(-2, 3 * self.row_length + 3)
        ax.set_ylim(-2, 3 * self.row_length + 3)
        ax.axis('off')

        divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
        cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)


        sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
        sm.set_array([])

        cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
        cbar.set_label('ADC value', color=WHITE, rotation=270, labelpad=10)
        cbar.ax.tick_params(colors=WHITE)
        cbar.outline.set_edgecolor(WHITE)
        plt.show()

For some reason, cbar.ax.tick_params(colors=WHITE) does nothing to change the color of the tick labels, though all the other edits work.
"WHITE" is just defined elsewhere as #FFF so it should work. I have also tried with 'white'. I have tried looking for other arguments/methods for axes or the tick labels, including iterating over the ticks in a loop but nothing works.
Here is an example of the generated image
Every other color change in the function works aside from the one for ticks.

Did you try cbar.ax.tick_params(which='both', color='white', labelcolor='white')? With a log norm of unknown range, possibly only minor ticks are visible. Note that your code isn't reproducible, making it hard to guess what exactly is going on. As the hexagons aren't important for the colorbar, you could remove a lot of code, and create a real minimal reproducible example.

there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

@JohanC Indeed cbar.ax.tick_params(which='both', color='white', labelcolor='white') seemed to solve the issue. It seems that targeting the minor ticks specifically solves it. I was under the impression that the color bar displayed major ticks as default, which is what I tried in my approaches, though it seems that instead minor ticks are displayed.

It seems that plt.colorbar() was adding minor ticks to the generated colorbar, as opposed to major ticks. I assumed that major ticks are the default as I found minor ticks to be generally OFF, though in this case it was wrong.
@JohanC provided the solution with cbar.ax.tick_params(which='both', color='white', labelcolor='white'). It seems that LogNorm may be the culprit (still unsure as to how ticks are determined here and whether major ticks may be visible instead for a different range)
Here is the colorbar segment as I currently have it:
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.set_label('ADC value', color=WHITE, rotation=270, labelpad=10)
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='minor', color=WHITE, labelcolor='white')
cbar.set_ticks([])


It is hard to know what's going on without knowing the range of the values. In general, if only secondary ticks are shown, the range is extremely limited (no power of 10 inside the range), and it makes more sense to not use a log norm.

The range of possible values is normally within 0 and 2048, however the effective range is not previously known (experiment-dependent).
In this particular case I do have a very small range. I will keep this in mind.
